# Как сделать чтоб при удалении середнего блока все другие с'ежались один к одному а не стояли на месте?

Tags: html, css, frontend

```
<div class="card">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="card__inner">

       <div class="card__item">
        <div class="card__header">
          <img src="assets/img/cars/img_1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="card__content">
          <div class="card__title">
            <h3>
              <a href="cars.html">Range Rover S64 Coupe</a>
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card__price">
            <span>$2500</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card__spec">
            <ul class="specs">
              <li class="specs__item">
                <span>Doors</span>
                <span>4</span>
              </li>
              <li class="specs__item">
                <span>Seats</span>
                <span>5</span>
              </li>
              <li class="specs__item">
                <span>Transmision</span>
                <span>Automatic</span>
              </li>
              <li class="specs__item">
                <span>Year</span>
                <span>2020</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="card__footer">
            <div class="card__button">
              <button class="btn btn--card">More Vehiles</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div><!--card__item-->

       

       <div class="card__item">
        <div class="card__header">
          <img src="assets/img/cars/img_1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="card__content">
          <div class="card__title">
            <h3>
              <a href="#">Range Rover S64 Coupe</a>
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card__price">
            <span>$2500</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card__spec">
            <ul class="specs">
              <li class="specs__item">
                <span>Doors</span>
                <span>4</span>
              </li>
              <li class="specs__item">
                <span>Seats</span>
                <span>5</span>
              </li>
              <li class="specs__item">
                <span>Transmision</span>
                <span>Automatic</span>
              </li>
              <li class="specs__item">
                <span>Year</span>
                <span>2020</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="card__footer">
            <div class="card__button">
              <button class="btn btn--card">More Vehiles</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div><!--card__item-->

       <div class="card__item">
        <div class="card__header">
          <img src="assets/img/cars/img_1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="card__content">
          <div class="card__title">
            <h3>
              <a href="#">Range Rover S64 Coupe</a>
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card__price">
            <span>$2500</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card__spec">
            <ul class="specs">
              <li class="specs__item">
                <span>Doors</span>
                <span>4</span>
              </li>
              <li class="specs__item">
                <span>Seats</span>
                <span>5</span>
              </li>
              <li class="specs__item">
                <span>Transmision</span>
                <span>Automatic</span>
              </li>
              <li class="specs__item">
                <span>Year</span>
                <span>2020</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="card__footer">
            <div class="card__button">
              <button class="btn btn--card">More Vehiles</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div><!--card__item-->`введите сюда код`


.card {
  margin-top: 200px;

  &__inner {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

  }

  &__item {
    width: 32%;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    padding: 25px;

    background-color: $white;
    box-shadow: $shadow;
  }

  &__header {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 220px;
    margin: -25px -25px 0;
    
    img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }

  &__content {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  &__title {
    text-align: center;
    color: $yellow;
  }

  &__price {
    margin-top: 10px;

    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: $gray; 
  }

  &__spec {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
}
```

Comment: не совсем понял суть вопроса, добавьте деталей в вопрос, а так же желательно css или приведите пример, желаемого результата

Comment: исправил, смотрите все блоки стоят попорядку, если я удаляю середний блок(просто стираю код), то два других  остаються на месте, мне нужно чтоб они смещались один к одному, тоесть если удалить середний блок, правый блок сместился к левому, как сделать, помоги пожалуста

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на grid

```css
.card {
  margin-top: 200px;
}
.card__inner {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid: auto/repeat(2, 1fr);
  justify-items: space-between;
}
.card__item {
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}
.card__item:nth-child(2n) {
  justify-self: end;
}
.card__item:nth-child(2):last-of-type {
  justify-self: start;
}
.card__header {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 220px;
  margin: -25px -25px 0;
}
.card__header img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.card__content {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.card__title {
  text-align: center;
  color: yellow;
}
.card__price {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: gray;
}
.card__spec {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card__inner">

            <div class="card__item">
                <div class="card__header">
                    <img src="assets/img/cars/img_1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="card__content">
                    <div class="card__title">
                        <h3>
                            <a href="cars.html">Range Rover S64 Coupe</a>
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__price">
                        <span>$2500</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__spec">
                        <ul class="specs">
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Doors</span>
                                <span>4</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Seats</span>
                                <span>5</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Transmision</span>
                                <span>Automatic</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Year</span>
                                <span>2020</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__footer">
                        <div class="card__button">
                            <button class="btn btn--card">More Vehiles</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--card__item-->

            <div class="card__item">
                <div class="card__header">
                    <img src="assets/img/cars/img_1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="card__content">
                    <div class="card__title">
                        <h3>
                            <a href="#">Range Rover S64 Coupe</a>
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__price">
                        <span>$2500</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__spec">
                        <ul class="specs">
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Doors</span>
                                <span>4</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Seats</span>
                                <span>5</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Transmision</span>
                                <span>Automatic</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Year</span>
                                <span>2020</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__footer">
                        <div class="card__button">
                            <button class="btn btn--card">More Vehiles</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--card__item-->

            <div class="card__item">
                <div class="card__header">
                    <img src="assets/img/cars/img_1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="card__content">
                    <div class="card__title">
                        <h3>
                            <a href="#">Range Rover S64 Coupe</a>
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__price">
                        <span>$2500</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__spec">
                        <ul class="specs">
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Doors</span>
                                <span>4</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Seats</span>
                                <span>5</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Transmision</span>
                                <span>Automatic</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Year</span>
                                <span>2020</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__footer">
                        <div class="card__button">
                            <button class="btn btn--card">More Vehiles</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--card__item-->

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: не помогло, можно же как то флексами?

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на flex

```css
.card {
  margin-top: 200px;
}
.card__inner {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-items: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.card__item {
  width: 32%;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}
.card__item:nth-child(2n) {
  margin-left: auto;
}
.card__item:nth-child(2):last-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.card__header {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 220px;
  margin: -25px -25px 0;
}
.card__header img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.card__content {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.card__title {
  text-align: center;
  color: yellow;
}
.card__price {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: gray;
}
.card__spec {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card__inner">

            <div class="card__item">
                <div class="card__header">
                    <img src="assets/img/cars/img_1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="card__content">
                    <div class="card__title">
                        <h3>
                            <a href="cars.html">Range Rover S64 Coupe</a>
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__price">
                        <span>$2500</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__spec">
                        <ul class="specs">
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Doors</span>
                                <span>4</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Seats</span>
                                <span>5</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Transmision</span>
                                <span>Automatic</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Year</span>
                                <span>2020</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__footer">
                        <div class="card__button">
                            <button class="btn btn--card">More Vehiles</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--card__item-->

            <div class="card__item">
                <div class="card__header">
                    <img src="assets/img/cars/img_1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="card__content">
                    <div class="card__title">
                        <h3>
                            <a href="#">Range Rover S64 Coupe</a>
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__price">
                        <span>$2500</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__spec">
                        <ul class="specs">
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Doors</span>
                                <span>4</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Seats</span>
                                <span>5</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Transmision</span>
                                <span>Automatic</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Year</span>
                                <span>2020</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__footer">
                        <div class="card__button">
                            <button class="btn btn--card">More Vehiles</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--card__item-->

            <div class="card__item">
                <div class="card__header">
                    <img src="assets/img/cars/img_1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="card__content">
                    <div class="card__title">
                        <h3>
                            <a href="#">Range Rover S64 Coupe</a>
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__price">
                        <span>$2500</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__spec">
                        <ul class="specs">
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Doors</span>
                                <span>4</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Seats</span>
                                <span>5</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Transmision</span>
                                <span>Automatic</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="specs__item">
                                <span>Year</span>
                                <span>2020</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__footer">
                        <div class="card__button">
                            <button class="btn btn--card">More Vehiles</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--card__item-->

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: снова не помогло